# Use collections with cargo without stdlib

Tags: embedded, rust, rust-cargo

I am currently trying to setup an embedded Rust project. For that it would be nice if I could use the `collections` crate (and by extension the `alloc` crate since it is required by `collections`). Is there an easy way to achieve this? I currently have the following dependencies in Cargo.toml

```
[build-dependencies]
gcc = "0.3"

[dependencies]
rust-libcore = "*"

[dependencies.rlibc]
git = "https://github.com/hackndev/rlibc"
branch = "zinc"
```

And use them as follows:

```
#![no_std]
#![crate_type="staticlib"]
#![feature(lang_items)]
#![feature(start)]

// This is not found when building with Cargo
extern crate collections;

//#[cfg(target_os = "none")]
extern crate rlibc;

#[start]
pub fn main(_argc: isize, _argv: *const *const u8) -> isize {
    // or some call like this
    core::collections::Vec::new();

    0
}
```

Is there an easy way to include the `collections` crate?

Comment: Do you have some underlying allocator to use on your embedded device? I don't know if jemalloc supports ARM, and if not, there would have to be some allocator available.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to compile it yourself. This requires having a checkout of the Rust source. I don't have a working environment to test this in, so take this suggestion with a pinch of salt. Conceptually, you would do something like this:

```
cd $RUST_SRC_DIR
rustc --version --verbose | grep commit-hash # Grab the hash
git checkout $RUSTC_HASH
mkdir cross-compiled-libraries
rustc --target=arm-whatever-whatever -O src/libcollections/lib.rs \
      --out-dir cross-compiled-libraries
```

Repeat the last step for whatever libraries you need. A lot of this is taken from the ideas in [Embedded Rust Right Now!](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/20/rust-language-c-embedded/).

A big concern with this solution is that libcollections requires an allocator. Generally, there is jemalloc or the system allocator. I don't know if either are available on the target you are compiling for...

This doesn't quite get you all the way to something easy to use for Cargo, either. The stuff inside of Rust isn't actually Cargo-ified yet, either. You *could* create a new Cargo project and add something like this to the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
path = "/path/to/rust/src/libcollections/lib.rs"
```

Which would then allow you to rely on Cargo more.